# php-Auto Subtract from Multiple Join Table

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table from these 2 tables using `LEFT JOIN` :

1. Input (code, name, quantity1)
2. Output (code, name, quantity2)

What I'm trying to do is to subtract those quantity (total=quantity1-quantity2), so the final table will have structure like this (code, name, quantity1, quantity2, total).

```
    <tr>
       <td> Code </td>
       <td> Name </td>
       <td> Quantity In </td>
       <td> Quantity Out </td>
       <td> Total </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
       include "koneksi.php";
       $query = "SELECT A.`code` , A.`name` , A.`quantity1` , B.`quantity2` FROM `input` AS A LEFT JOIN `output` AS B ON B.`code` = A.`code`";
       $sql = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
       while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$data['code']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data['name']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data['quantity1']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data['quantity2']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data['total']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       }
    ?>
```

I knew how to do Auto Sum/Substract if only the input in text type (the quantity input manually), but in this case the quantity come from two another tables. I'm quite new on this, hope anyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: The real question is, why do you want to do it at the database level, instead of just substracting it in php?

Comment: It is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to substract it in php, but I can't find the code to do it since those quantity is not input manually, but came from two another tables. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Would you please show me where I should put that code, exactly? Thanks

Comment: echo "<td>".($data['quantity1'] - $data['quantity2'])."</td>";

Comment: It works like a miracle. Thank you very much :)